# oh my zsh showing weird character '?' on terminal

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, powerline

I have installed iTerm2 and Oh-my-zsh. However there is a weird question mark that is coming ever since I have changed ZSH-THEME to "agnoster".

Attaching the screenshot for the same.

[image: check the question mark on terminal pointer]

I thought powerline would help but that doesn't seem to happen. Can can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you installed powerline fonts?

Comment: yes I have installed powerline fonts

Comment: And have you pointed your iTerm to use that font? I suppose you were following this tutorial ? https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/8568070

Comment: yes, I was following this tutorial, but I am unable to point iterm to fonts!

Comment: What exactly are you unable to do ? You can't find the font in the list ? You can't find the window where to change it ?

Comment: I tried doing this : iterm2 > preferences > profiles > text Regular font & non ASCII font. But I could not find non ASCII font

Comment: solved! point 6 of this article https://coderwall.com/p/yiot4q/setup-vim-powerline-and-iterm2-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Added this as answer to the question, easier for future searches.

Answer (score 69):

This has fixed the issue. Just select `Use built-in Powerline glyphs` and use `Inconsolata for Powerline` font.

[image: This has fixed the issues.]

Comment: This worked for me, but one extra thing I had to do was to apply these changes to not just the default profile in iterm2, but also my user-specific profile ("jeff")

Answer (score 60):

Installing a powerline patched font will solve this. [This official documentation](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#fonts-installation) provides description about installing poweline fonts.

There are two ways to enable powerline patched font in iTerm2.

1. Set a powerline patched font as default.

[image: One defauls font]

2. Set a powerline patched font for only Non-ASCII characters and use another font for code.

[image: Different fonts]

**Bonus:**

- [Collection of powerline patched fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)
- Awesome oh-my-zsh themes

  - [Spaceship ZSH](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-zsh-theme)
  - [Buller Train](https://github.com/caiogondim/bullet-train.zsh)
  - [powerlevel9k](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k)

Answer (score 17):

Just do the following, it worked for me, trust me, see the truth in my eyes.

Go to preference->Profiles->Test and look at the following figure:-
[image]

Answer (score 7):

On Windows - just 
* download some Powerline font like:
https://github.com/abertsch/Menlo-for-Powerline/raw/master/Menlo%20for%20Powerline.ttf
* Install it by clicking the file twice
* Choose the new font in properties
That's it!

On Mac - the previous answer in totally correct, just install and choose an appropriate font.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by Going to **iTerm2->Settings->Profiles->Text** and enabling "Use built-in Powerline glyphs". That fixed the seperators but not the icons.

The icons were fixed by changing to a font that support them. Such as those listed here: https://github.com/powerline/fonts

I already had one installed called "FuraCode Nerd Font" but think this might have been renamed to "Fira Code" or something not quite sure. But you need to have a font that supports the icons.

Answer (score 0):

This answer relates to a similar problem I encountered but for the `oh-my-posh` application on Windows 10 Pro.

For others who might be wrestling with this, I also was having issues where the font would create tiny boxes with question marks. Turns out it was because my version of Windows 10 Pro was not activated. I found this out by trying to search for Fonts in the settings, and was unable to search for any of the Nerd Fonts I thought I had downloaded. Activating Windows 10 Pro fixed the problem as soon as I reloaded.